# JavaScript Infinite scroll + lazy loading - how to prioritize HTTP requests (it's eating available connections)?

Tags: javascript, http

I've built on my website custom infinite scroll that simply loads 6 next or 6 previous posts depending on the scroll direction by calling API endpoint:

```
$.get('/api/post/' + chunkToLoadNow + '/' + categoryToLoad + '/', function (response) {
   // appends or prepends a container with some html content
}
```

This works perfectly. The point is that appended or prepended HTML also contains lazy loading class for images so as soon as the markup is injected and the section is in a viewport, plugin makes 6 http requests for 6 thumbnails. Makes sense.

Imagine that I scroll down, it loads (injects) content for 6 posts and automatically activates 6 http requests for images and then I scroll even faster and now next HTTP call to my `/api/post/2/0` won't be called until lazy loading plugin finish fetching images which I don't care about because they belong to a chunk that is above the viewport (I'm interested in next ones).

The final effect is that when I scroll fast enough, it will inject markup for 2 chunks and requests 12 images, the 3rd chunk will have to wait a long time, users will get nuts.

Is there a JS way to quit opened HTTP requests that already started but not finished? Or can I somehow explicitly set priority to API endpoints as more important as HTTP requests for jpegs in my website?

Comment: Did you optimize the images to reduce the loading time? Not sure why the users will go nuts form waiting for 12 thumbnails to load

Comment: Because the thumbnails are in a top notch quality. These images are small but the file weight is decent…

Comment: @slick maybe use a good cache to speed up the delivery or your images, and use two images: one good quality and one pretty small for the thumbnail.

Comment: @slick I'm not sure why this has to be synchronous. You can continue scrolling and displaying data and using lazy load you can populate them with the images when they are received from the server. Can you post a minimal working example with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You may abort an image load request by changing its src:

```
img.src = '';
```

For normal ajax requests you can do something like:

```
var req = $.ajax(...); 
req.abort();
```